# set_password() method is saving plain text

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

When I'm saving the user from the view and writing the codes it is saving the password as plain text but when I'm using the same set_password() method in the shell, it's saving the hashed password perfectly. Kindly point out where I'm making the mistake. Actually I'm saving the data directly from an excel sheet.

```
username="username"
password="password"
firstName="first"
lastName="lastname"
user=User.objects.create(
            firstName    =   firstName,
            lastName     =   lastName,
            username     =   username,
        )   
        user.set_password(password)

        user.is_student = True
        user.school = request.user.school
        user.save()
        user_ins = User.objects.get(username=username)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change as follows

```
 user = User.objects.create_user(username=username, password=password, first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

set_password only creates a hashed password; it doesn't save the value in the data. Call save() to actually save it.

In your code, try

```
user.save()
```

below the line

```
user.set_password(user.password)
```